# Objective-C syntax: <>

Tags: objective-c, syntax

```
@interface A : B<C>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<MSBClientManagerDelegate>
```

So I guess I get A is subclass of B, and B is superclass of A, but what's the relationship between B and C?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example above, `C` is a protocol.  What you're saying in english terms is:

I want a class `A` that subclasses from class `B` and also conforms to protocol `C`.

A protocol is similar to an abstract class in other languages and usually defines a set of methods and or properties that a class must implement in order to conform.

Answer (score 0):

As C is a protocol so `A` conforms to protocol `C`.

Answer (score 0):

`C` is a protocol that defines a set of methods and or properties that a class must implement and/or can implement if it is defined as optional.